# Why the code exit ant don't complete

Tags: c, gcc

I am a beginner in C programming. I try to make a code of array that user make its size and enter some variable to sum.

The problem that during the executing, it stops in the middle of code!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
int size = 0; // handle the array input[] size.
int input[size];
int total = 0;
int n = 0; // count the element want to sum.


printf("how many variable you want to sum: ");
scanf("%i", &size);

int i;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("enter integer %d",  i+1);
    scanf("%d", &input[i]);
    
    
}

int j;
for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    total += input[i];
}

printf("Result is: %d", total);
return 0;
}
```

The error that I get in the terminal:

> how many variable you want to sum: 5
>
> Result is: 0
>
> ---
>
> (program exited with code: 12)
>
> Press return to continue

**What is the problem I have made??**

Comment: Move `int input[size];` after `scanf`. Also initialize `n = size` here.

Comment: `n` is always zero! perhaps you meant size not `n`

Comment: Variable length array is a C99 feature. Did you make sure that you're compiling in C99 mode? Also, reindent your code and remove any unneeded spaces and lines

Comment: You are not using `size` anywhere after getting it's value from user!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place

```
int input[size];
```

after reading `size`(that's how variable length array should be declared).
Also take `n` not to `0`. I think it should be

```
n = size;
```

Comment: I did. I put int input[size] after getting the size from the terminal.

But I get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your loops are controlled by `n`. You set `n` to `0` at the beginning of the program and never changed it

```
int n = 0; // count the element want to sum.

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) // <== n is 0

for (j = 0; j < n; j++) // <== n is 0
```

Comment: I uninitialized n (int  n;). and I get the same error.

Comment: That's even worse: now you're invoking **Undefined Behaviour** because you're using an uninitialized variable!

Comment: Thanks i discovered the error it was that to make the array after getting the n. and i was confusing by making two varaibles for size and use the both.

Answer (score 0):

```
int input[size];
```

-> The size of array can not be got in the run time. If you want to do that, you may use malloc().

The following code, without malloc() yet, may works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    int input;
    int total = 0;
    int n = 0; // count the element want to sum.
    int i;

    printf("how many variable you want to sum: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("enter integer %d", i);
        scanf("%i", &input);
        total += input;
    }

    printf("Result is: %d", total);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes, but the target from the code to manipulate with array. and controlling its size.

Comment: int * input = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  scanf("%i", input[i]);
}
free(input);